# MATLAB insert character separated with space from GUI

Tags: matlab

I need to input characters from a GUI but they need to be separated by spaces. Every time a new character is added, it should be appended to the existing array.
For example:

- user enters `'a'`, the content of array is `'a'`
- if user enters `'b'` next, the content of array is `'a b'`

**Edit 1**

These lines of code should be inside the `pushbutton1_callback` function, so whenever the user presses the button, a new character should be added to static text; separated by a space.

**Edit 2**

My only line of code in here is:

```
letter = get(handles.edit1, 'string')
```

Comment: What is your code doing so far?

Answer (score 1):

Without details I can provide a conceptual solution.

Initialize the variable that holds the text to:

```
txt = '';
```

Then the callback will do:

```
txt = strtrim(sprintf('%s %s',txt, get(handleToTextBox,'String')));
```

Comment: I need to do this inside pushButton1_callback function, my only line of code in here is: letter = get(handles.edit1, 'string'). So whenever user press this button, one letter should be added to static text, but those letters have to be separated by space.

Answer (score 1):

```
letter = get(handles.edit1, 'string');
global txt;
txt=[txt letter];
txt=[txt ' '];
set(handles.text1, 'string', txt);
```

That's how I solved it.